# how do I choose specific items from a list using python and save in a new list

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x

I am writing a code in Python (3) that checks a product code is in a certain format. the codes are entered as a variable and then split into a list. I have two issues. The products are both letters and numbers and I wish to check they conform to my prescribed arrangement; it should be 4 letters 1 space and 4 numbers then 2 letters .

The code below seems to work but when checking data validation it appears that .isdigit allows # or other symbols.

I want to make more elegant and try and use a for loop to check specific items  are letters eg [0,1,2,3,10,11] but cannot understand how to only check these specific items in the list

```
if (len(ProductCode) == 12 and
    ProductCode [0].isalpha and
    ProductCode [1].isalpha and
    ProductCode [3].isalpha and
    ProductCode [4].isalpha  and
    ProductCode [5]== ' ' and
    ProductCode [6].isdigit and
    ProductCode [7].isdigit and
    ProductCode [8].isdigit and
    ProductCode [9].isdigit and
    ProductCode [10].isalpha and
    ProductCode [11].isalpha):
        message = 'Next Product'
else:
    message = 'Non-Standard Product Code'

print(message)
```

Comment: So `ProductCode` is a string? Why are you not using a Regexp? Also `isdigit` and `isalpha` are methods, so use them as `isdigit()` and `isalpha()`. Can you give an example of a typical productcode?

Comment: Also, `len(ProductCode)` should be `11`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Why convert `ProductCode` to a list? It's easier to examine as a string even if it needs to be turned into a list afterwards.

Comment: Thank you putvande, I am new to programming (less than a year) an example of the product code is swee 0001bl  So far I have asked the user to input the product code as a string then I was splitting it into a list so I could test each character. I had taken this from another programme I found online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a regular expression:

```
import re

if re.match('\w{4} \d{4}\w{2}', ProductCode):
    message = 'Next Product'
else:
    message = 'Non-Standard Product Code'
```

This matches something like `AbcD 1234Az` (4 alphanumeric, space, 4 digits and 2 alphanumerics)

So if you only want letters instead of the alphanumerics, change the pattern to:

```
[a-zA-Z]{4} \d{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}
```

Comment: `\w` means [a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: What's with the extra slashes? You should make regex patterns a raw string `r'...'`.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks. @LittleQ `isalpha` does that too.

Comment: @putvande so the OP is asking for help

Comment: Still wrong - "\w" will match numbers too  : `re.match('\w{4} \d{4}\w{2}', "1111 1111ZZ")`. The right regexp is `r'[a-zA-Z]{4} \d{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}'`.

Comment: OP is using `isalpha` there, so guess OP wants to match alphanumerics?

Comment: `str.isalpha()` returns `False` for numerics :  `"a42".isalpha()` => False. And the OP explicitely stated he wanted letter, not alnums (in which case he would have used `isalnum()`).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, this one is taxing me. Just to clarify using I should use re.match

Comment: Thank you for your comments, this one is taxing me. Just to clarify I tried using  re.match('\r{4} \d{4}\r{2}', ProductCode):       I have tried the \w and as mentioned it allows [a-zA-Z0-9]  so thought I had to use \r for [a-zA-Z] but it thinks letters are non standard.

Comment: Figured what you meant. I used                                                          import re

if re.match('[a-zA-Z]{4} \d{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}', ProductCode):
    message = 'Next Product'
else:
    message = 'Non-Standard Product Code'                                                                     thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is Just an example of how you can loop through the list you want, you can apply it to your needs

```
letters_list = [0,1,2,3,10,11]

def check_letter(ProductCode):
  global letters_list
  for l in letters_list:
    if not ProductCode[l].isalpha: return False
  return True

if check_letter(ProductCode): print("Everything in list is a letter") #define ProductCode 
else: print("Something is wrong")
```

Comment: It'd be better to pass in `ProductCode` and then let `letters_list` be implicitly global without passing it. Since the former is likely to be redefined with multiple values and the latter will likely just be the same value throughout.